# how do i prevent respond.js reading my retina display media query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, media-queries

I have added respond.js to activate media queries in ie7+8, the problem that Im having though is that ie7+8 now seem to read the retina display media query which as you can imagine is messing up my layout. Has anyone else experienced this problem and if so how can this be prevented?

```
    @media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
}
```

**Update for anyone having the same problem:**

Basically I moved any hd media queries into their own .css file (hd.css) then added a conditional statement into the  section of my site that prevents lte IE 8 from seeing it.

Comment: you need to hide such things from the innocent eyes of IE7-8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add a class specific to IE detection (if you haven't already) to your html tag with jQuery, a lot like [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) does for browser capabilities. Then wrap the styles within the media query:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

   html.no-ie div#mydiv{
      /* STYLES FOR #mydiv HERE */
   }

}
```

Detect the browser with jQuerys **$.browser** property and add a class to your html tag (with version...because...why not?):

```
/* CHECK IF BROWSER IS IE */
if($.browser.msie){
   /* GET THE BROWSER VERSION...BECAUSE WE CAN! */
   var version = $.browser.version;

   /* ADD CLASSES FOR BROWSER + VERSION TO HTML TAG ie. <html class="ie ie6"> */
   $('html').addClass("ie ie" + Math.floor(version));
}
```

Hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the "only screen" references from your media query, so that it reads:

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
(min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){

}
```

Comment: Yes, but if I did that then the larger logo would override the smaller, mobile retina logo. There's media queries with sizes for retina and those without, those without sizes are ignored by respond.js, but those that use max or min, get picked up by respond.js and old IE will take them and display the 2x version of the logo and since it doesn't understand background size, it's totally messed up.

Answer (score 1):

with boilerplate's document head, I added a class "modern" to the last conditional without conditions the one with the <!--> before the html tag:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js es lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js modern" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

then in my retina css -- if the retina css is inside a media query with max and min (this why respond.js reads it), I have:

```
.modern #logo a { /*w & h LOGO */
    background-image: url(../images/logo_@2x.png);
        -moz-background-size:200px 81px; /*w & h of original 72dpi image REMEMBER THIS IS THE LARGE LOGO*/
         -ie-background-size:200px 81px;
          -o-background-size:200px 81px;
     -webkit-background-size:200px 81px;
             background-size:200px 81px;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a combination of Steve O's and Christina Arasmo Beymer's answers:
To be a little more specific to media queries capabilities i included css-mediaqueries detection into my [custom build of Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/download/#-fontface-backgroundsize-borderimage-borderradius-boxshadow-flexbox-hsla-multiplebgs-opacity-rgba-textshadow-cssanimations-csscolumns-generatedcontent-cssgradients-cssreflections-csstransforms-csstransforms3d-csstransitions-applicationcache-canvas-canvastext-draganddrop-hashchange-history-audio-video-indexeddb-input-inputtypes-localstorage-postmessage-sessionstorage-websockets-websqldatabase-webworkers-geolocation-inlinesvg-smil-svg-svgclippaths-touch-webgl-shiv-mq-cssclasses-addtest-prefixed-teststyles-testprop-testallprops-hasevent-prefixes-domprefixes-css_mediaqueries-load).
Then you have a `mediaqueries` class in your html tag, don't have to write your own JS or manually add a class to your html.

Now you can do:

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
  html.mediaqueries #element {
  }
}
```

If you use Compass i can recommend this mixin: [Retina-Sprite-for-Compass](https://github.com/AdamBrodzinski/Retina-Sprites-for-Compass)

Comment: I think this is the best solution since it leverages Modernizr.

Answer (score 0):

My very simple solution exploits the bug's core issue in order to fix itself.  The root problem is that respond.js sees the -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio property, doesn't know what to do, and simply ignores it, incorrectly showing the style block.  My solution is to copy the whole media query block, paste it in the css right after and change '-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio' to '-webkit-useless-fake-property' then make all the css rules a negation of the previous block.  respond.js will ALSO ignore this, pass it through and it will undo the previous block!

Example:

```
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2) {
    #selector {
        background-image:url("img2x.png"); /* 1000 x 400 */
        background-size:500px 200px;
    }
}
@media all and (-webkit-useless-fake-property:2) {
    #selector {
        background-image:url("img.png"); /* 500 x 200 */
        background-size:auto;
    }
}
```

Seeing as this is really only for retina images there wont be many rules to 'undo'.  Browser that don't have their head under a rock and their fingers in their ears will use native CSS3 and simply ignore the -webkit-useless-fake-property media query.